# How to save mongodb data sub data more properly in this case?

Tags: mongodb

I have a business collection.

The businesses are reviewed by users.

Each user can only review a business once. Future reviews will simply replace the former one.

This is how we store it:

```
 "Reviews" : {
    "gusyanto" : {
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:08 am",
      "review" : "Tes review"
    },
    "sapi" : {
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:18 am",
      "review" : "makanan ini sangat enak"
    }
  }
```

Alternatively we can also use this:

```
 "Reviews" : [{
      "userid" : "gusyanto",
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:08 am",
      "review" : "Tes review"
    },
    {
      "userid" : "sapi",
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:18 am",
      "review" : "makanan ini sangat enak"}
    ]
  }
```

So basically we want can store it as a dictionary where the key is the `userid` or we can store it as an array where `userid` is the field key. So the key in the second approach is static, namely `userid`.

We want to index the entries. For example, a user may want to know what businesses he has reviewed.

Which approach I should use?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, MongoDB queries are more optimized for your second approach.

with the first approach you will probably have to do a query like:

```
db.businesses.find({'Reviews.gusyanto': {$exists: true}})
```

Which is *less efficient* than using:

```
db.businesses.find({'Reviews.userid': 'gusyanto'})
```